# Missing records when fetched from kinesis data stream using getRecords

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to get all records from kinesis data stream to display as continuous feed on web page. Using the PHP script below I am not getting all records that are being pushed into the data stream using aws agent (on the server).

I find data missing when fetched from getRecords() vs data landing in S3 using firehose consumer to the same data stream

Here is the code that I am using, can someone point me what am I doing wrong

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Kinesis\KinesisClient;

$streamName = 'DATA-STREAM-NAME';
$kinesisClient = KinesisClient::factory(array(
                                        'region' => 'eu-west-1',
                                        'version' => '2013-12-02'
                                            )
                                    );

// Get shard list
$shardList = $kinesisClient->listShards([
    'StreamName' => $streamName,
]);

// Iterate through shards to get iterators
$iterators = array();
foreach ($shardList['Shards'] as $shard) {
    $shardIterator = $kinesisClient->getShardIterator([
        'ShardId' => $shard['ShardId'],
        'ShardIteratorType' => 'LATEST',
        'StreamName' => $streamName
    ]);
    $iterators[$shard['ShardId']] = $shardIterator['ShardIterator'];
}

// Loop continuously to get feed from kinesis
while (1) {
    $iterators = getLogs($iterators);
    sleep(3);
}

// Get records from each iterator
function getLogs($iterators) {
    global $kinesisClient;
    $nextIterators = array();
    foreach ($iterators as $key => $iterator) {
        $records = $kinesisClient->getRecords(['ShardIterator' => $iterator]);
        $nextIterators[$key] = $records['NextShardIterator'];
        if (empty($records['Records'])) {
            return $nextIterators;
        }
        foreach ($records['Records'] as $data) {
            echo $data['Data'];
        }
    }
    return $nextIterators;

}
```

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: Not yet, I have been advised to use timestamp instead of LATEST. I haven't tried the solution yet hence can't comment if it would work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing (I think). The problem I ran into is that I was assuming that if there no records in one iterator there won't be any in subsequent iterators.  You just have to keep going until you've read them all.  In fact in my case almost all of the iterators (> 99%) are empty which is causing my code to run forever retrieving empty iterators.  I'm hoping to find a solution to that!